# Can a function remember variables between numerous calls?

Tags: c, memory, scope

I am trying to create a function that will take in the positions of numerous bodies moving in circular motion, and output their orbital periods. Each body is stored in a struct which contains its X, Y and Z co-ordinate (as well as some other information I don't need for this specific task).

My current function for doing this is:

```
double calc_period(Body *bodies, double t, int Nbodies, int i)
{
    double orbit_angle[Nbodies];
    double initial_angle[Nbodies];
    double last_angle[Nbodies]
    double last_time[Nbodies];
    double half_step[Nbodies];
    double running_total[Nbodies];
    double orbitN[Nbodies];
    double average_period[Nbodies];
    
    orbit_angle[i] = atan(bodies[i].r[Y] / bodies[i].r[X]);
    
    if (t==0) {
        //Initialise all the variables to 0 the first time through
        last_angle[i] = 0;
        initial_angle[i] = orbit_angle[i];
        orbitN[i] = 0;
        half_step[i] = 1;
    }
    
    if (last_angle[i] < initial_angle[i] && orbit_angle[i] > initial_angle[i]) {
        if (half_step[i] == 0) {
            if (orbitN[i]==0) {
                last_t[i] = t;
                running_total[i] = t;
            } else {
                running_total[i] += t - last_t[i];
                last_t[i] = t;

            }
            orbitN[i]++;
            average_period[i] = running_total[i] / (DAYS_TO_SECS * orbitN[i]);
            half_step[i] = 1;
        } else if (half_step[i] == 1) {
            half_step[i] = 0;
        }

    }
    last_angle[i] = orbit_angle[i];
    
    return average_period[i];
}
```

and this function is called in main like so:

```
for (double j = 0; j < max_time; j += timestep) {
    update_positions(bodies, Nbodies, j);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nbodies; i++) {
        average_period[i] = calc_period(bodies, j, Nbodies, i);
        if (j > max_time - timestep) {
            printf("%s average period: %lg\n", bodies[i].name, average_period[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

and the problem that I'm having is that of course when the calc_period function finishes, the variables within are destroyed, so it cannot remember what initial_angle, last_angle or last_t were, so doesn't work. However I'm struggling to come up with a solution for this. If anyone can give any guidance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can make them static, however it's probably a better solution if you stash the data into a struct and pass it to the function.

Comment: Aside you might consider using one array of `struct` containing all the properties, instead of a battery of arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, because I'm giving them the length Nbodies (which doesn't change during one run of the code, but can change between runs), and you cannot make a static array with a variable size.

Comment: But you have other properties in the type `Body`.

Comment: Well, either have an upper bound and keep them static, or then put the necessary data into the `Body` struct, OR have an auxiliary data structure that holds the extra information for N amount of bodies.

Comment: Or have a `static` pointer variable, and allocate it with `malloc` when the function is first called.

Comment: Of course! I didn't think about creating a new struct to store the required information in. Thank you @vmt!

Comment: Note that 'static' makes your function thread-unsafe.  That may, or may not, matter now, or ever.  Just pointing that out:)

Answer (score 0):

Any data in the stack is volatile within function calls. The space in the stack you are using now will be replaced on future function calls, so functions on the stack should be used just until the function ends.

For your problem different methods exists.

You can create a struct as a global variable which will be stored in BSS, you can create a global pointer pointing to your struct on dynamic memory, allocated with functions like malloc().

Also you can create a static variable so on future calls to that function you can use it.

The best solution would be either defining a static pointer to malloc() where your struct resides, or doing the same on a global variable as a pointer.